# Rails best way to create a conditional link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the link_to tag below and i'm curious as to what the best way is to create this link and also check if the first_name and last_name are nil?

I still want to have a link if only one of the names is nil (first or last).

```
<%= link_to "#{u.user_details.first_name+" "+u.user_details.last_name}", profile_path(u), :class => 'name' %>
```

Comment: what about using link_to_if ?
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clean way to achieve this would be

```
class UserDetails
  def full_name
    [self.first_name,
     self.last_name].compact.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Then, in the controller

```
<%= link_to(u.user_details.full_name,
            profile_path(u),
            :class => 'name') if u.user_details.full_name.present? %>
```

With `link_to_if`, the `'name'` parameter would be returned if the condition is not filled, and you don't need it since it will be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

For my taste there's too much code in the view. I'd prefer to use the model and a helper:

```
# user_details.rb
def full_name
  "#{first_name} {last_name}"
end

# helper.rb
def my_link_to(user)
  name = user.user_details.full_name
  return "" if name.blank?
  link_to name, profile_path(user), :class => 'name'  
end

# view.erb
<%= my_link_to user %>
```

Comment: With `"#{first_name} {last_name}"`, if one of them is blank, you will have a blank space at the beginning or the end of your `full_name`.

Comment: You're right, it should be `"#{first_name} {last_name}".strip`

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor string like this: `"#{[u.user_details.first_name, u.user_details.last_name].join(' ')}"`.

Check out how [`#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) works first.

Downside of this solution is that link will be created even if there is no user details provided, but it will have empty anchor string.

Answer (score 0):

A working method is :

```
<%= link_to "#{u.user_details.first_name+" "+u.user_details.last_name}", profile_path(u), :class => 'name' if u.user_details.first_name.blank? or u.user_details.last_name.blank?  %>
```

But I'm not sure this is the best way...

Answer (score 0):

Quickly:

```
<%= link_to_if u.user_details.first_name || u.user_details.last_name,
[u.user_details.first_name, u.user_details.last_name].compact.join(' '),
profile_path(u), :class => 'name' %>
```

I might, however, refactor it to something like:

```
<% a = [u.user_details.first_name, u.user_details.last_name].compact %>
<%= link_to_unless a.empty?, a.join(' '), profile_path(u), class: 'name' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also check they are not [blank](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) and use `join` :

```
<% name = [u.user_details.first_name, u.user_details.last_name].reject(&:blank?).join(" ") %>
<%= link_to name, profile_path(u), :class => 'name' unless name.blank? %>
```